# ExactTarget - get a report of all emails sent to individual subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

is there a way to get all of the emails that were sent to individual subscriber (all or for the period of time) with dates of email being sent, and the name of email?

Comment: Just to verify: are you aware of the canned reports within the email application, and these just are not working for you?  Have a look at http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/reports/

Comment: I could not find a report that would show all of the emails that were sent to individual subscriber. They could be different types and are sent from different DE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a Query Activity.
1.  Create a destination Data Extension.
2.  Create a query activity to get this data for you.  I used :

```
SELECT j.EmailName, s.EmailAddress from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE se.EventDate < GetDate()
```

And use your newly created DE for the destination for this query activity.  Use ORDER BY to order however you like.

3. Run the Query
4. (Optional) For a report, create a data extract, and extract the data extension.  You can then move it using a File Transfer activity to an FTP server you already have set up.

After this is all set up, you may chose to put "Run Query, Extract, and Transfer" all in any Automation within Automation Studio.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Timothy Is it possible to create a report based on the email and segment them based on some attribute?

Comment: Yes.  You could write a query activity to do it.

Comment: I guess this still shows only last 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

For non-SQL, we found this:

Under Audience Builder, click on Contact Builder
Then all Contacts tab
Then select channel
Then search by email address
That shows you everything that contact has been sent, and whether they've opened, clicked or 'converted'

Answer (score 0):

In this query - do you insert your own data?

```
SELECT j.EmailName, s.EmailAddress from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE se.EventDate < GetDate()
```

eg

```
SELECT j.newsletter2, s.my@email.com from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.1234567
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.567859
WHERE se.EventDate < 23/09/2016()
```